# Internet radio software where I can add my preferred stations

Tags: osx, streaming, radio

Can anyone recommend a light Internet radio application for the Mac? I want one where I can add my own addresses.

Most of the apps I have found have thousands of built-in radio stations or use a subscription. All I want is a bare one I can fill in with my own preferred stations.

Recording would be nice, but not essential.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html). It supports MacOS, Linux, and Windows. It also has [Internet Radio (“Shoutcast”) support](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html). I have used it (on Windows), and you can directly enter an address for a radio station.

If you want to record, you could probably do this with [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org) or [StreamRipperX](http://streamripperx.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

## iTunes

The [iTunes app with its “Internet Radio” feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes#Internet_radio) meets your requirements. Bundled with every Mac. Already knows hundreds of streams, grouped by genre.

You can type or paste the URL for any stream you want. Save that to a playlist for future use.

**Retraction:** I no longer recommend *iTunes* for open streaming. Apple is now interested only in selling *Apple Music* subscriptions.

Apple had previously taken steps to bury the “Internet Radio” streaming feature beneath two layers of user-interface, hiding it entirely from unaware users.

Now in iTunes version 12.9.4.94, when trying to save a bookmark to return to a station, Apple hides the command as a context-click menu item on the "Now Playing" bar… and even worse… when choosing that command, Apple instead tries to sell you an Apple Music subscription.

For details of these problems, see: [*“Internet Radio” gone from iTunes 12.7*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298536/17907) on the sister site, AskDifferent.com.